# Google SignIn returns Current user as null

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, google-signin

I am using google login for my Xamarin iOS app, however after successfully entering the username and password in the safari browser prompt that appears, It returns properties CurrentUser as null.

My Code:

```
Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.Delegate = this; 
Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.UIDelegate = this; 
Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser(); 
Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.SignedIn += SharedInstance_SignedIn;

private void SharedInstance_SignedIn(object sender, SignInDelegateEventArgs e) 
{ 
var signin = (Google.SignIn.SignIn)sender; 
   //Here if i debug signin variable, its property CurrentUser comes as null
}
```

I am using 
Xamarin.IOS.Google.Signin: v4.0.1.1

Am I missing some setting that needs to be enabled in the Google api console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sender` indicate the class that raised the event.

To get **User** ,you can  use `e.User` Or `Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.CurrentUser`

[here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiossignin) explatins the function of method `SignIn`

> The Sign-In SDK automatically acquires access tokens, but the access tokens will be refreshed only when you call SignIn or SignInSilently methods.

Comment: Okay I get CurrentUser, If I add Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser() which triggers SharedInstance_SignedIn event.

 But if I dont add Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser() it doesnt trigger the event

Comment: @NathanN and you question?

Comment: Is Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.SignInUser() necessary for the SharedInstance_SignedIn event to be fired? In my case the event gets fired only if I add the above line

Comment: I can't see the source code ,but I think it is .  Since `access token`  is necessary and required every time when you login, you need to refresh it unless  call the `RefreshAccessToken` method , so if you don't call  `SignInUser()` or `SignInUserSilently ` , it will fail in the connection , and the callback method will not fired.

Comment: thanks alot .
I have another query, is there a similar callback method for Xamarin.Ios.GooglePlus for log-in?

Comment: You mean the callback method when login with Google+ account in  `Xamarin.IOS.Google.Signin`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155566/discussion-between-nathan-n-and-cole-xia).