# Google SignIn Delegates not firing in Xamarin. iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-signin

Google SignIn delgate method
public void DidSignIn () 
Is not getting called. But it asks for login credentials but after success login (I guess it doesn't show anything else )
It goes back to viewcontroller ViewWillAppear method but nothing. GoogleUser instance is null. I have tried solutions in this [google signin not calling delegate method after success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383280/google-signin-not-calling-delegate-method-after-success) but nothing is working. Also sometimes OpenUrl () in AppDelegate does not get invoked.

Answer (score 1):

> Google SignIn delgate method public void DidSignIn () Is not getting called

Did you implement `ISignInDelegate` and call `SignInUser()` or `SignInUserSilently ()`?

> GoogleUser instance is null

To get User ,you can use `e.User` Or `Google.SignIn.SignIn.SharedInstance.CurrentUser`

> Also sometimes OpenUrl () in AppDelegate does not get invoked.

Did you add `your.app.bundle.id` and `value of REVERSED_CLIENT_ID from GoogleService-Info.plist`  in `Info.plist`?

Please refer to [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482680/8187800)

#### Update (Solution)

Remove the event `SignedIn` and leave the Delegate alone.

It seems there are conflict between them.

Comment: Yes . I did call SignInUser().  i did add REVERSED_CLIENT_ID but as a URLScheme.

Comment: I also using FCM .Is there a possibility of dlls issues ?

Comment: Could you try the [official sample](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleiossignin/true) first?

Comment: The fact is this used to work . The only change was FCm and imported my project from VS 2013 to VS 2017. i also have Facebook integrated it works fine.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem, I suggest you use [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth), it contains both Google and FB login.

Comment: @ Cole Xia - MSFT I was using  SignIn.SharedInstance.SignedIn += (sender, e) event and also Delegate methods DidSignIn() .Seems like both of them in the same controller does not seem to work in new Xamarin update.

When i removed the Event and only put Delegate methods , it's working.